# python script calling another script

Tags: python, function

I wrote a python script that works. The first line of my script is reading an hdf5 file

```
readFile = h5py.File('FileName_00','r')
```

After reading the file, my script does several mathematical operations, successfully working. In the output I got function F.

Now, I want to repeat the same script for different files. Basically, I only need to modify FileName_00 by FimeName_01 or ....FileName_10. I was thinking to create a script that call this script!

I never wrote a script that call another script, so any advice would be appreciable.

Comment: You can look into argparse to pass in command line arguments

Comment: Why? Just get all the file names and loop over them, or make a loop that increments the digits.

Comment: I did that. I create a loop that increment the digits. But I realized that my script operations are only applied to the last file

Comment: Well, you need to store the results in a list.  `readFile = []` / ... `readfile.append( h5py.File(f"FileName_{index:02d}",'r'))`.

Comment: @Shmack - it's a matter of preference. one may want a command-line script that operates on one file (then use something like `xargs` or a bash for loop to apply that script to multiple files).

Comment: @Shmack, I create this loop
for counter in range (0,10):
    readFile = h5py.File('FileName{}'.format(counter),'r')
But later I need to read the function F from each file
F = np.array(readFile['F'])[:,:,:,:]
By doing so, the script only keeps in memory the last readFile, so I only have F corresponding to the last readFile. Besides, I am doing many operations on F. One of my object is to keep F for each file and calculate the mean

Answer (score 0):

One option: turn your existing code into a function which takes a filename as an argument:

```
def myfunc(filename):
  h5py.file(filename, 'r')
  ...
```

Now, after your existing code, call your function with the filenames you want to input:

```
myfunc('Filename_00')   
myfunc('Filename_01')
myfunc('Filename_02')
...
```

Even more usefully, I definitely recommend looking into

```
if(__name__ == '__main__')
```

and `argparse` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) as jkr noted.

Also, if you put your algorithm in a function like this, you can import it and use it in another Python script. Very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Although there are certainly many ways to achieve what you want *without* multiple python scripts, as other answerers have shown, here's how you could do it.

In python we have this function `os.system` (learn more about it here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system). Simply put, you can use it like this:

```
os.system("INSERT COMMAND HERE")
```

Replacing `INSERT COMMAND HERE` with the command you use to run your python script. For example, with a script named `script.py` you could conceivably (depending on your environment) include the following line of code in a secondary python script:

```
os.system("python script.py")
```

Running the secondary python script would run `script.py` as well. FWIW, I don't necessarily think this is the best way to accomplish your goal -- I tend to agree with DraftyHat's solution in most circumstances. But in case you were curious, this is certainly an option in python. I've used this functionality in the past, albeit not to run other python scripts, but to execute commands in the shell. Hope this helps!

Comment: consider replacing `os.system` with `subprocess.run`. please see the note in the linked documentation regarding `os.system`: "The `subprocess` module provides more powerful facilities for spawning new processes and retrieving their results; using that module is preferable to using this function."